# Libmtp in windows (msys/mingw): Run problems

Tags: dll, mingw, mtp

Hi i need a windows port of [libmtp](http://libmtp.sourceforge.net) ([github_link](http://github.com/libmtp/libmtp)). So i compiled libmtp under Msys/MingW Environment.

The build is successful and i have no error on build, but in runtime i have error. When function (LIBMTP_Get_Connecte_Devices) is called, the return value of this function is (LIBMTP_ERROR_CONNECTING).

```
LIBMTP_mtpdevice_t* device_list;
LIBMTP_error_number_t x = LIBMTP_GET_CONNECTED_Device(&device_list);
// x = LIBMTP_ERROR_CONNECTING
```

Can anyone can solve my problem?

In addition, where can i found prebuild versions of libmtp (libmtp-9.dll) for  windows?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because libmtp needs libusb to connect to your device.

There are builds on the [OpenSUSE Build Service](https://software.opensuse.org/package/mingw32-libusb-1_0)