# libmtp in cygwin environment: LIBMTP_PANIC Error

Tags: cygwin, libusb-1.0, mtp

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52801967/libmtp-in-windows-msys-mingw-run-problems) on building libmtp on mingw/msys. Now i compiled libmtp in cygwin. I am using libusb ver 1.0.21 (pre instilled from cygwin). When i run the examples i got error that is showed in the picture below:

[image]

I tested this on multiple systems. but all are the same.
Any idea?

Note: Libusb tested and works well.

Comment: Have you built it or just installed a binary version ?

Comment: I built libmtp. But i installed binary version of **libusb**, **libiconv** packages.